# How to manage hosts network namespaces from docker container

Tags: linux, docker, networking, namespaces

My aim is to manage network namespaces on host using an application which runs within latest docker container (ver. 17.12).

I tried starting docker container with following options:

```
docker run -ti --entrypoint=/bin/bash --network=host --pid=host --    
privileged --cap-add ALL -v /run:/run debian
```

This allows me to create a network namespace on host however once the container is destroyed the network namespaces created from within container are still visible but I am unable to use them.

```
container # ip netns add test
container # exit
host # ip netns
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
test
testhost
host # ip netns exec test ip addr
setting the network namespace "test" failed: Invalid argument
```

Any idea how to start docker container so the application running within it can manage hosts network namespaces ?

Comment: Have you tried mounting `/etc/` as a volume as well?

Comment: @DerekBrown just tried, no change. Why do you think mounting /etc from host would help ? I straced the "ip netns" command and they only try to open /etc/netns which doesn't exist in container or host alike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution which I found is to start a docker with binding /proc from host and using nsenter to change the mount namespace.

```
host # docker run .... -v /proc:/host/proc /bin/bash
container # nsenter --mount=/host/proc/1/ns/mnt ip netns add test
```

Comment: That leaves the container's namespace though – I don't think you can eg. run `ip netns exec $container_binary`